# How to parse Cordova/Phonegap file upload in flask app

Tags: python, cordova, flask, request, file-transfer

I've been working on a Cordova app, using the Ionic framework. I'm trying to do a "File Transfer" to a my Python-Flask back-end, but I keep getting "400 Bad Request". I'm quite sure that the error is caused by the request parsing method in flask (I'm currently using "request.file[]").

But I can't seem to figure out how to parse the POST request properly.

The POST is send in chunkedMode, with the mime type "image/jpeg", not sure if this could have any impact (My Nginx proxy is set up to properly receive POSTs in chunked mode).

My client code:

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                    // Succes
                    function(imageURI){
                        // Upload image
                        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                        options.fileKey = "file";
                        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                        options.trustAllHosts = true;
                        options.chunkedMode = true;
                        var ft = new FileTransfer();
                        // Initiate upload
                        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://192.168.1.53/"), 
                            // Succes
                            function(succes){
                                alert(succes.response);
                                console.log(succes.response);
                            }, 
                            function(error){
                                alert(error.target);
                                console.log(error);
                            }, 
                            options
                        );
                    },
                    // Error
                    function(message) {
                        console.log('get picture failed'); 
                    },
                    // Options
                    { 
                        quality: 100, 
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        allowEdit : false,
                        correctOrientation: true,
                        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY 
                    }
                );
```

I got this working in PHP, witht the following code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["somefile"]))
{
        //Filter the file types.
        if ($_FILES["somefile"]["error"] > 0)
        {
          echo "error:" + $_FILES["somefile"]["error"];
        }
        else
        {       
           callSomeFunction();
        }

} // End of function
```

My current flask app looks something like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["file"]
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
            #fileStream = file.stream
            #print(opencvDataFromStream(fileStream))
            #processImage(filename)
            return processImage(filename)
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    """
```

As you can see it returns a form, and when the POST is send through the form, the request is treated as expected.
But when the POST request is send through the cross side Cordova client, I get the bad request error.

Would any one happen to know how to fix this?

Sincerely a flask n00b.

Answer (score 1):

So I screwed up...
The error was simply caused, due to the fact, that the fileKey ("imageToScan") parameter in the client wasn't the same fileKey as my Flask back-end was expecting ("file").